# Is there any methods to get the like list of a tweet?

Tags: twitter, web-crawler

I want to get the complete like list of a specific tweet, but the [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/likes/api-reference/get-tweets-id-liking_users) only provided an API that can retrieve the 100 most recent users who liked the specific tweet. I also looked for Twitter crawlers on Github, but they all worked in a user-oriented manner, ie they can only get a list of liked tweets of a user, not a list of liking users of a specific tweet.

I also tried to crawl the list using selenium, but maybe due to my limited skill, it didn't work well. I don't want to spend a lot of time studying selenium and front-end knowledge just to accomplish a simple thing, so are there any open source codes or twitter APIs that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This has [just been announced](https://twittercommunity.com/t/updates-to-retweets-lookup-and-likes-lookup-endpoints/165327) in the Twitter API v2.

> Previously, you were limited to the 100 most recent Likes or Retweets with these endpoints. We heard your feedback that this was too limiting and have updated these endpoints to now return all results. To retrieve a complete list of Likes and Retweets, you can now use [pagination](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/pagination).

Use the [v2 Likes lookup endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/likes/introduction): `GET /2/tweets/:id/liking_users`

Comment: OMG, it wasn't available yesterday... what a coincidence! Thanks!